# How to I add another User's mailbox to my favorites in outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have read access to another person's mailbox and I can open it by going to the File Menu and selecting "Open and Export" and then "Other User's Folder" and typing in the mailbox name.

But then when I switch back to my own mailbox I lose the view of the 2nd mailbox and can't get it back without going through the whole process again.

How can I add the 2nd mailbox to the navigation pane on the left hand side of my outlook so that I can open it from there?

Comment: I know this is similar to this outlook 2010 question but I thought I would put the answer for outlook 2013 up here too. http://superuser.com/questions/191103/how-do-i-add-another-users-inbox-to-my-favorite-list-in-outlook-2010

Answer (score 1):

You can add a mailbox to your Navigation using the following method:

Go to your mailbox name in the Navigation pane, right click and choose "properties"

Click on the "Advanced" button 
[image]

and then the "Advanced" Tab
[image]

Click the "Add" button, and type in the name of the account.
[image]

Press OK, and then press OK again.
Check that the new mailbox has shown up in your Navigation pane. It will usually be below your main mailbox.